# How to improve readability of typescript errors?

Tags: typescript

Currently typescript errors out with the following style:

```
Argument of type '({}: {}) => IterableIterator<SimpleEffect<"TAKE", TakeEffectDescriptor> | SimpleEffect<"CALL", CallEffectDescriptor> | SimpleEffect<"PUT", PutEffectDescriptor<Action<Success<any, any>>>>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ context: {}; fn: (this: {}, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.
```

How can we improve this so that its more readable, by that I mean even simply

```
Argument of type 

  '({}: {}) => IterableIterator<SimpleEffect<"TAKE", TakeEffectDescriptor> | SimpleEffect<"CALL", CallEffectDescriptor> | SimpleEffect<"PUT", PutEffectDescriptor<Action<Success<any, any>>>>>' 

is not assignable to parameter of type 

  '{ context: {}; fn: (this: {}, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.
```

would suffice.

Comment: Wow that's quite the type!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message formatting isn't customizable as far as I know.  There is an [old, closed issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16978) which requested this, but the answer there was just to make it so that the IDE should behave better with the existing message.

Along a similar vein, there's [a more recent, open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29059) asking to make wordy error messages collapsible and expandable. Again, this only makes sense inside an IDE, and the relevant work here is in [an issue for VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64566).  It looks like in general the trend has been to make IDEs behave differently in the face of complex error messages, instead of trying to manipulate the string representation of the error messages .

It's also possible that in some cases no way of formatting the existing error message is helpful, and you'd like to use a completely custom error.  In that case, there's [an open feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) proposing an "invalid" type like `Invalid<T>`, which would cause a compiler error if you ever try to use it, and would output a custom error message encoded by the type `T`.

If any of the open issues seem useful to you, you might want to go over there and give them a  and/or describe your use case if it's more compelling than what's already listed.  Or, if not, you could always [open a new feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md) asking for it.

Anyway, hope that's of some help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/yoavbls/pretty-ts-errors

At least for VSCode, there is a more convenient error formatting available.